# TFS2010 - Work Item Types - Link to a program?

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want a LinkLabel to link to a program (and not to an http-URL). But in work items the only allowed link type seems to be "http" ... how can I create a link in my work item type, that links to a program in my local network like \server1\path2\program3.exe with parameters from the work item's input?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use the `file:///c:/myfolder/myapp.exe` syntax ?

It works to save the link in the Work Item.

[image]

Comment: I tried it and got the error TF237077, saying, that "file" is not allowed and I should use http(s) or mailto.

Comment: Weird, which version of VS/TFS do you use? Because I can do it, look at the picture I added in the Answer.

Comment: I do not want to link from an work item to a program, as I can link it to changesets or other work items. I want a hyperlink in the work item dialog, defined in the work item type definition. This LinkLabel should open/run a program.exe

Comment: Ok, I just got it, you want a Work Item Form control that display a Work Item field containing an URI that point to a program. What is the specific type of Form Control you tried? LabelControl ? FieldControl ?

Comment: I tried a <FieldControl> with a <Link ...> in the <text> for this control.